# Delay in linux socket communication

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, strace

I have a userspace application (no access to source code) that sends CAN bus data using socketcan APIs.

While sending the data of 64 bytes the application its facing a delay of 2 seconds between arbitrary frames (8 bytes)

The weird part is if I run the application using *strace* command, there is no delay, the data transfer gets finished in 200 ms.

This is the code flow in the kernel,
`sock_write_iter()` -> `sock_sendmsg()` -> `raw_sendmsg()` -> `can_send()` -> `__dev_queue_xmit()` -> `dev_hard_start_xmit()` -> `flexcan_start_xmit()`

Using `getnstimeofday()`, I can trace back the delay to `sock_write_iter()`, which is the kernel function of write handler of `socket()` system call.

Is there any way I can reduce the delay. I am not suspecting the Linux system call but the user space application. I also tried to increase the nice value still, the delay occurs.

Comment: *"I can trace back the delay"* - how did you do that? Is *"a delay of 2 seconds"* measured through `getnstimeofday()`?

Comment: at the end of the function, I saved the timespec and at beginning of the function I checked whether the difference is higher than a threshold.

Comment: Could you check the delay of `sock_write_iter()` through the [*`trace-cmd`*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/trace-cmd-record)? What is the point of writing something yourself and recompiling the kernel when everything you need is already provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to a smaller queue length for the CAN device.
Changing the trasnmit queuelen fixed the issue.

```
ifconfig can0 txqueuelen 100
```